# run a method on a Databinder.Eval object and convert to a string

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I have a repeater that outputs an image path.
I am trying to check if the file exists.
I am having issues with the method in the cs

```
public string doesImageExist(object sysid)
{
    string mySysid = sysid.ToString();

    string curFile = "C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\xxx\\xxx.com\\listings\\Photo" + mySysid + "-1.jpeg";

     if (File.Exists(curFile))
     {
         return "http://www.xxxx.com/listings/Photo" + sysid + "-1.jpeg";

     }
     else
         return "http://www.xxxx.com/images/multiple-listings.jpg"; // placeholder file
}
```

on the page I am using this code

```
<img class='img-rounded' 
     src='<%# doesImageExist(Eval(Container.DataItem, "SYSID"))%>' 
     alt='' style='float:left; width :350px; margin: 10px;' />
```

I have tried changing the method to accept a string and then add "as String" to the eval and it still did not work...
Thanks for any advice on this

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.UI.TemplateControl.Eval(string, string)' has some invalid arguments
and

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using overload of `Eval` and call `ToString()` to pass string to server side method.

```
src='<%# doesImageExist(Eval("SYSID").ToString())%>'

public string doesImageExist(string sysid)
{
      //your code
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I had to remove the Container.DataItem in the eval...
Can you explain why this worked without the Container.DataItem??

Comment: You shouldn't need to, this is code I use on an old project GetProfilePicture(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Picture").ToString())%>'

Comment: yeah, its weired it only worked after I replaced 
    <%# doesImageExist(Eval(Container.DataItem, "SYSID"))%> 
with
    <%# doesImageExist(Eval("SYSID").ToString())%>

Comment: The only difference I see with mine is that I have DataBinder.Eval and you had Eval, the rest would have been the same after adding the ToString()

Answer (score 0):

You can use ToString()

```
<img class='img-rounded' 
     src='<%# doesImageExist(Eval(Container.DataItem, "SYSID").ToString())%>' 
     alt='' style='float:left; width :350px; margin: 10px;' />
```

and then change the method back to string as the param

```
public string doesImageExist(string sysid)
```